# Solving equations in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ versus $\mathbb{Q}_p$.

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, diophantine-equations, p-adic-number-theory, arithmetic-geometry

According to Silverman:

> In order to show that an algebraic set $V/\mathbb{Q}$ has no
>   $\mathbb{Q}$-rational points, it suffices to show that the
>   corresponding homogeneous polynomial equations have no nonzero
>   solutions modulo $p$ for any one prime $p$ (or even for one prime
>   power $p^r$). A more succinct way to phrase this is to say that if
>   $V(\mathbb{Q})$ is nonempty, then $V(\mathbb{Q}_p)$ is nonempty for
>   every $p$-adic field $\mathbb{Q}_p$.
>
> (The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves, p.8.)

I don't see how the two statements are related:

> **Question.** What's going on here?

Comment: $\Bbb{Q}$ is a subset of all $\Bbb{Q}_p$ so I would think that $V(\Bbb{Q})$ would be a subset of all the $V(\Bbb{Q}_p)$, $p$ varies.

Comment: I think what Silvermann means is that if you have an algebraic set $V/\mathbb{Q}$ and you homogenize it then you are looking at solutions in $\mathbb{Z}$ for your homogenized form. If a solution does exist then it exists $\mod{}p$ for every prime $p$. Now you will have a solution in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ and since $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is it's field of fractions you get a solution in $\mathbb{Q}_p$ for your original system of polynomial equations.